# Get UID of the device's NFC Card with Android

Tags: java, android, nfc, uniqueidentifier

I'm developing an application in which I want to get the NFC serial number of a device. When I press a button, I want the application to find the UID of the NFC card and store it in a DB. The only problem is that I have no idea how to get the UID and if that's possible on Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do you read the unique ID of an NFC tag on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060312/how-do-you-read-the-unique-id-of-an-nfc-tag-on-android)

Answer (score 4):

Please read doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html

`Tag` have method `getId()` :

> Get the Tag Identifier (if it has one).
>
> The tag identifier is a low level serial number, used for
>   anti-collision and identification.
>
> Most tags have a stable unique identifier (UID), but some tags will
>   generate a random ID every time they are discovered (RID), and there
>   are some tags with no ID at all (the byte array will be zero-sized).
>
> The size and format of an ID is specific to the RF technology used by
>   the tag.
>
> This function retrieves the ID as determined at discovery time, and
>   does not perform any further RF communication or block.

It could be something like this:

```
@Override protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        Log.d(TAG, "tag ID = " + tag.getId().toString());
    }
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```