# Is there any possibility to duplicate the UID of NFC?

Tags: android, nfc

I hope to use `NFC cards(UID)` to identify the employees using android app. And I have to assign this `UID` over 10'000 employees. Therefore I need to make sure the possibility of the duplication over this concept. I have captured the `UID` as below.

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

    if(tag == null){
        textViewInfo.setText("tag == null");
    }else{
        byte[] uid=tag.getId();
        String finalUID= Base64.encodeToString(uid,1);          
    }
}
```

"finalUID" have send & saved in the mysql table. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverfow. Do you have any problem with the android code you posted or are you just asking about the uniqueness of the UID you're extracting/reading from the NFC tag?

Comment: Hello, I'm asking the uniqueness of the UID and I want to make sure that "Am I used correct extracting/reading method ?(that mentioned above).

Comment: So I would recommend reading these two questions and their respective answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060312/how-do-you-read-the-unique-id-of-an-nfc-tag-on-android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700718/serials-on-nfc-tags-truly-unique-cloneable, as your question seems to be a duplicate of these

Comment: Thanks lot dude that post is help me lots... Anyway, whats about the method that I used to read UID on tags?